# Passing a PHP variable from a div tag to jquery when clicked

Tags: php, javascript

I have a requirement to get a variable from PHP to Javascript when clicked by the user. I have an array of data returned by a query and I need to pass an ID value for the element clicked so that I can populate an additional data set via the .load using another PHP page. I am unsure how todo this?

Javascript Code in Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () { 
 $("#pass_userid_div").click(function () {
    
    $("#another_div").load('remote_pages/get_info.php?userid=' + $GET_THE_USERID_AND_PASS_HERE);
  });
});
</script>
```

PHP Code in Page:

```
$query_str = "SELECT id, username, dateregistered FROM users";
$query = mysql_query($query_string) or die(mysql_error());

while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    print "<div id='pass_userid_div'>{$results['username']}</div>";
    print "<div>{$results['dateregistered']}</div>";
}
```

Comment: Like `'remote_pages/get_info.php?userid=<?php echo $userid; ?>'`?

Comment: why are you printing multiple divs with the same `id`?

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'php variable' once the page is sent to the client. There's only what's in the rendered webpage - text/tags/numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why must it be a div? Use an [interactive element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/interactive-elements.html#using-the-button-element-to-define-a-command):

PHP:

```
while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    print "<button type='button' name='pass_userid_div' value='{$results['id']}'>{$results['username']}</button>";
    print "<div>{$results['dateregistered']}</div>";
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () { 
 $("button[name='pass_userid_div']").click(function () {
    $("#another_div").load('remote_pages/get_info.php?userid=' + $(this).val());
  });
});
</script>
```

Update: If it *really* must be a div, [use a `data-` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#custom-data-attribute):

```
<div class="pass_userid_div" data-userid='{$results['id']}'…

…$(this).data("userid")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#another_div").load('remote_pages/get_info.php?userid=' + $GET_THE_USERID_AND_PASS_HERE, function(){
    $("#another_div #pass_userid_div").each(function(){
        var yourvar =$(this).text();
        // use your var
     })
});
```

Please not you should not use more then one div whith the same id. Use `class` instread

Comment: I deleted my previous comment since you fixed part of it, but this still relies on the id `pass_userid_div`, which is duplicated in OP's code and assumed to be a descendant of `#another_div`. Fix that and I'll rescind my downvote.

Comment: Haven't noticed while loop. Can't get which varaible does OP need